# How to write method to close matplotlib figure using TkAggBackend

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm embedding a matplotlib figure into tkinter.  I've tried writing a method to use plt.clf(fig), get_tk_widget().destroy(), etc...  In my searches, I've found nothing that documents examples of methods/functions closing embedded graphs from backend.

I am obviously missing something here but I'm really new tkinter.  I simply cannot find a way to write a method such that I can call get_tk_widget().destroy(). I'm not sure how to reference my widget from the method that will close it. I think it's probably a simple reference error based on how I'm defining in **init** but I don't know tkinter well enough to know for sure.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename as getname

import numpy as np

from datetime import datetime


Large_Font = ("Arial", 12)

style.use("ggplot")

class ratgraph(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "RA Trend Grapher")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Main Page", font=Large_Font)
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Open Trend File", command=lambda: self.RetrFileName())
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Close Graph", command=lambda: self.CloseGraph())
        button2.pack()

    def RetrFileName(self):
        fname = getname(initialdir="C:/Users/Zibit/Desktop/",
                        filetypes=(("RA CSV File", "*.csv"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
                        title="Load a Trend")

        fname = fname.replace("\\", "/")

        data = np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter=",", dtype=(str, str, "U40", float, float, float),
                             names=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])

        x = [datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S;%f") for i in data["c"]]
        y = data["d"]

        ToDateFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%M:%S:%f")

        f = Figure(figsize=(8, 5), dpi=96)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ToDateFmt)
        a.plot(x, y, label="Carriage Current Output")
        plt.setp(a.get_xticklabels(), rotation=15)
        '''

        plt.xlabel("Time")
        plt.ylabel("Amps")
        plt.title("RA Trend Grapher")
        plt.legend()

        '''

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()

        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    def CloseGraph(self):
        ??? get_tk_widget().destroy() ???
```

Any help or links to examples would be appreciated.

Comment: What about `plt.close(fig)`?

Comment: I've tried that.  I receive reference issues, as if I cannot simply refer to the figure.

Comment: @thomas-kühn   Sorry, rushing to leave for work here, couldn't edit above comment in time.  I've tried that.  Even if I put that directly after the load of the Figure and `canvas.show()`, it does not close the figure.